# Logo not appearing on some pages in ASP.net webforms title

Tags: asp.net, html, css

ill try my best to explain this..

in the site.master I have added a logo to the title like so.

```
<div class="title">
               <img alt="" class="style1" src="Images/logo.png" />     
</div>
```

the logo shows up fine in all pages accept when the url is part of the account.

for example..

"http://localhost:54341/Sitename/mypage.aspx" (shows fine)

however

"http://localhost:54341/Sitename/Account/Register.aspx" (doesnt show)

im guessing its because it is in a parent folder (the images file).

Is there a better way?

EDIT: Images folder is at the top level

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using relative path with respect to root of the application:

```
   <img alt="" class="style1" runat="server" src="~/Images/logo.png" />
```

**Explaination:**

ASP.NET includes the Web application root operator (~), which you can use when specifying a path in server controls. ASP.NET resolves the ~ operator to the root of the current application. You can use the ~ operator in conjunction with folders to specify a path that is based on the current root.

The following example shows the ~ operator used to specify a root-relative path for an image when using the Image server control In this example, the image file is read from the Images folder that is located directly under the root of the Web application, regardless of where in the Web site the page is located.

```
<asp:image runat="server" id="Image1"
  ImageUrl="~/Images/SampleImage.jpg" />
```

You can use the ~ operator in any path-related property in server controls. **The ~ operator is recognized only for server controls and in server code. You cannot use the ~ operator for client elements.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply... however when I try that it doesn't show up on any page...wierd

Comment: Thank you that worked a treat Kevin.. how do I mark that as the answer. thanks heaps

Comment: @clockworkworks glad I could help :) Just mark this as the answer now it has been updated with that info

Comment: @kevinMain , ok I marked the main answer as the answer and upvoted your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
  <img alt="" class="style1" src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/logo.png")%>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin Main suggested : You need to put runat="server" on the image for this to work.. this worked  a treat

Answer (score -1):

This will work for `localhost:54341/Sitename/Account/Register.aspx`

```
<img alt="" class="style1" src="../Images/logo.png" />
```

Comment: @mohang: this will work for http://localhost:54341/Sitename/Account/Register.aspx

Comment: @KevinMain suggested : You need to put runat="server" on the image for this to work..

Comment: @clockworkworks: but previously you have used img tag so and for localhost:54341/Sitename/Account/Register.aspx is not working so i suggest to use " ../ ". well i agree with KevinMain also.